# Is it possible to assign cursor.fetchall() to a variable?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

```
rows_order = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM 'Order'"
            cursor.execute(rows_order)
            ordernum = cursor.fetchall()
            connection.commit()

cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Order' (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
                [ordernum], custid_Sorder, now, total_item_price))
```

This is what I am trying but this error popped up;

```
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

How do I fix this? I want to make it so the OrderNo is = to the amount of orders before it, hence why I want to assign the orderno to it.  (I am using sqlite3)

Comment: So if the first query found, say, five orders, you want to use 6 as the new order number?  Then you would use `ordernum[0][0] + 1`

Comment: Why are you making your first param a list? Only a single string is expected there.

Comment: If your intent is to provide a unique numeric id, it is better done with an [auto-incrementing primary key](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html). `ordernum integer primary key`. If for some reason that doesn't work, use `max(orderno)`. Consider if you delete a row, [1, 3, 4]. `count(*)` will return 3 which is taken.

Answer (score 1):

as you have only one value you need only fetchone

```
import sqlite3
con = sqlite3.connect("tutorial.db")
cursor = con.cursor()
rows_order = "SELECT COUNT (*) FROM 'Order'"
cursor.execute(rows_order)
ordernum  = cursor.fetchone()[0]
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'Order' (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost) VALUES (?,?,?,?)", (
                ordernum, custid_Sorder, now, total_item_price))
```

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** Don't do this. Use an [auto-incremented primary key](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

---

[`fetchall`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchall) returns all rows as a list, even if there is only one row.

Instead, use [`fetchone`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.fetchone). This will return a single tuple which you can then select the first item. `ordernum  = cursor.fetchone()[0]`

However, you appear to be writing a query to get the next ID. Using `count(*)` is wrong. If there are any gaps in `OrderNo`, for example if something gets deleted, it can return a duplicate. Consider `[1, 3, 4]`; `count(*)` will return 3. Use `max(OrderNo)` instead.

---

Furthermore, if you try to insert two orders at the same time you might get a race condition and one will try to duplicate the other.

```
process 1                  process 2
select max(orderNo)
fetchone # 4
                           select max(orderNo)
                           fetchone # 4
insert into orders...
                           insert into orders...  # duplicate OrderNo
```

To avoid this, you have to do both the select and insert in a [transaction](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-transactions/).

```
process 1                  process 2
begin
select max(orderNo)...
fetchone # 4               begin
                           select max(orderNo)
                           fetchone
insert into orders...      # wait
commit                     # wait
                           # 5
                           insert into orders...
                           commit
```

---

Better yet, do them as a single query.

```
insert into "Order" (OrderNo, CustomerID, Date, TotalCost)
select max(orderNo), ?, ?, ?
from "order"
```

---

Even better ***don't do it at all***. There is a built-in mechanism to do this use an [auto-incremented primary keys](https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html).

```
-- order is a keyword, pluralizing table names helps to avoid them
create table orders (
  -- It is a special feature of SQLite that this will automatically be unique.
  orderNo integer primary key
  customerID int,
  -- date is also a keyword, and vague. Use xAt.
  orderedAt timestamp,
  totalCost int
)

-- orderNo will automatically be set to a unique number
insert into orders (customerID, orderedAt, totalCost) values (...)
```